# Sorting and aranging lists from txt files in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

Ive been given a task in which I have to sort scores from a test which are saved in txt files. I have to sort them alphabetically with only the highets score of each pupil showing , sorting the scores with the names highest to lowest and then the average scores highest to lowest. I have no idea other than using sorted() however that hasn't sorted it how I wanted it to.

```
the txt file looks like this:
James
3
8
4 
Jim 
6
2
10 
Tom
3
7
10 
Bob 
10
8
6
    This is my code:
class1 =[]
filename = 'class1.txt'
f = open (filename,'r')
class1 = f.read().splitlines()

class2 =[]
filename = 'class2.txt'
f = open (filename,'r')
class2 = f.read().splitlines()

class3 =[]
filename = 'class3.txt'
f = open (filename,'r')
class3 = f.read().splitlines()
def Menu():
    print(" How would you like the results sorted")
    print("Enter 1 to sort alphabetically with each students highest score    for the tests")
    print("Enter 2 to sort by the highest score highest to lowest")
    print("Enter 3 to sort by the average score highest to lowest")


WhichClass = input("What class would you like to sort 1,2 or 3")
while int(WhichClass)>3:
    WhichClass = input("Please enter 1,2 or 3")
if WhichClass == '1':
    Menu()
    MenuChoice = input()
    while int(MenuChoice)>3:
        MenuChoice = input()
    if MenuChoice == '1':
         print(sorted(class1))
```

However this code sorts it like this:

```
What class would you like to sort 1,2 or 31
How would you like the results sorted
Enter 1 to sort alphabetically with each students highest score for the tests
Enter 2 to sort by the highest score highest to lowest
Enter 3 to sort by the average score highest to lowest
1
['10', '10 ', '10 ', '2', '3', '3', '4 ', '6', '6', '7', '8', '8', 'Bob ',   'James', 'Jim ', 'Tom']
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: This looks like homework. If so, you should state that in you headline, and be more specific about what aspect you need help with. No one wants to do your homework for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you have a specific question about a problem you've run into, preferably with code that shows you've already done some effort and research, we'd be happy to help

Comment: Yes , this is homework I probably should have mentioned . I know your not a code writing service and I should have been more specific. Is their any built in functions or basic code that I can use to sort the list in the way I've said or have I put the data in the txt file wrong. I apologise for my mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a key=int to your sorted:

```
sorted(class1, key=int)
```

possibility of how you can use:

```
>>> class1 = ['James', '3', '8', '4']
>>> classDict = {}
>>> classDict[class1.pop(0)] = class1
>>> classDict
{'James': ['3', '8', '4']}
>>> classDict['James']
['3', '8', '4']
>>> sorted(classDict['James'], key=int)
['3', '4', '8']
>>> sorted(classDict['James'], key=int, reverse=True)
['8', '4', '3']
```

Comment: I can see the logic behind this however the program returns an error as invalid literal because of the clash of strings and integers in the same file ( I think) thanks for trying to help or am I being stupid.

Comment: @JamesPiper I added a example of how you can convert your list to a dict containing a list that can be sorted

Comment: Thank you I think this will help

Comment: np, i know it doesn't truly answer your question but hopefully it helps you get something working